# Jquery document.ready / asp.net event ordering

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to grab a variable that is created on document.ready during page load and spit it out in a literal or label tag by the time the page is done loading? So far I haven't been able to grab it.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context to the problem? There may be a better way.

Comment: Literal or Label are server-side controls that becomes something else (ordinary SPAN) on client-side. In `document.ready` - that SPAN should be accessible and you should be able do something like `$('#labelID').text(YourVariable)` right there

Comment: The scenario is on document.ready I am pulling values out of divs and building a string, I need to have this appear in a script tag as parameters for google marketing, the values are not available server side, its a custom 3rd party search tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<body>
   Here's a string, inside it is the ad client: <span id="ad_client">ca-pub-<PUB_ID_HERE></span>, and the ad slot: <span id="ad_slot"><AD_SLOT_HERE></span>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var ad_client = document.getElementById('ad_client').value;
var ad_slot = document.getElementById('ad_slot').value;

// Create the <script> element
var script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js';
    script.attributes.async = true;

document.body.appendChild(script);

// Create the <ins> element
var ins = document.createElement('ins');

    ins.className = 'adsbygoogle';
    ins.style = 'display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px';
    ins.dataset.adClient = ad_client;
    ins.dataset.adSlot = ad_slot;

document.body.appendChild(ins);

setTimeout(function() {
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}, 250)
```

Note that it worked fine for me without the setTimeout, but put it in there as a precaution. May be best to do it in a callback.